# Ajax fetching HTML not SQL results from node.js

Tags: node.js, json, ajax

I am trying to send my sql query results from node.js to my html.  When I log it in the console it shows the correct data, but once I add it to the "res.send" in a stringified format and try to retrieve it with ajax in index.html the object I get doesn't have the data, just my entire HTML code.

I've tried changing my ajax to many different things I found online but nothing changes.  I've tried changing POST to GET, changing the url (which just breaks it), only using success and not complete (which results in no object coming through).

```
node.js code excluding server code:

var sql = require('mssql/msnodesqlv8');

var config = {

  connectionString: 'Driver=SQL Server;Server=NAME-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=master;Trusted_Connection=true;'
};
sql.connect(config, err => {
  new sql.Request().query('SELECT * FROM Companies', (err, result) => {
    console.log("Works");
    if(err) { // SQL error, but connection OK.
      console.log("  Error: "+ err);
      JSON.stringify(err);
    } else { // All good.
      console.dir(result);
      JSON.stringify(result);
      app.get('/', function data(req, res, next) {
        res.send(JSON.stringify(result))
      })
    };
  });
});
sql.on('error', err => { // Connection bad.
  console.log("Bad");
  console.log("  Error: "+ err);
});
```

HTML Ajax code:

```
<script>
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: 'json',
  url: '/',
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  complete: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data);
  }
});
</script>
```

The object I end up with has a responseText that has all of the HTML code. Any idea what I am doing wrong that the response isn't my data?

Comment: did you try app.post instead of get

Comment: @AhmedSunny Just tried it, it seems to do the same thing.

Comment: remove json.stringify before app.get. only do once.  i think it doesnt make sense but could be in node

Comment: @AhmedSunny Good point, I did that but it is still giving the HTML.  I would assume it is a problem in the ajax but I wouldn't know considering I have no experience with using ajax and very little with node.

Comment: ok try one by one . remove contenttype because you are not sending any data to server.. and then remove stringify, and just send result and see

Comment: @AhmedSunny Unfortunately no luck.  Nothing changes which I find odd.  Would the results show somewhere other than responseText? The object has so much in it I cant find where something may change.